# Back/Forward buttons for UIWebView - canGoBack not working with ajax sites

Tags: objective-c, ios, ajax, ios5, uiwebview

I'm using some toolbar buttons for going back and forwards through historic webpages in a UIWebview.
[image]

I am enabling/disabling these buttons using `[webview canGoBack]` called at `webViewDidStartLoad`. Works fine on most sites, but the problem is, on sites like **twitter** and **facebook** who use javascript/ajax requests to reload new pages `canGoBack` and `canGoForward` do not recognise a page change so my buttons don't become active.

Is there a way round this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to cobble a solution together using [webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a):

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)myWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

I enable the back button at this point. Seems to work ok.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the site itself has to support back/forward on top of their AJAX requests. It would require the web application to change the URL for each page navigation.

See http://www.devx.com/webdev/Article/35549 for some discussion on this issue.

So, specific to your question - if it's your own web app, it's definitely possible (there are several javascript solutions, one of which is linked above), but for 3rd party web apps, I'd say no.

Answer (score 0):

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

  [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Please wait..."];

  if (webView.canGoBack) {
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnBack];
  } else {
      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
  }
  }